# Did J.K. Rowling give two or more unrelated characters the same first name in any of the 10 books?

Tags: harry-potter

When I say "the 10 books", I mean the seven *Harry Potter* novels, *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, *Quidditch Through the Ages*, and *The Tales of Beedle the Bard*. However, I will also gladly accept verifiable information from [Pottermore](http://www.pottermore.com) or further supplemental canon information from J.K. Rowling, such as information from interviews, articles, or material posted at [J.K. Rowling.com](http://www.jkrowling.com/) or the [Harry Potter Lexicon](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/).

Anyhow, the *Harry Potter* books are full of characters with interesting and unique names. I notice J.K. Rowling seems to like alliteration. For example: Luna Lovegood, Severus Snape, Pansy Parkinson, Padma and Parvati Patil, Daedelus Diggle, Quirinus Quirrell, Bellatrix Black, Peter Pettigrew, Mary MacDonald, Minerva McGonagall, and so forth. She has gone on the record, admitting her love for names, and for taking great care when assigning a name to a given character.

I know there are unrelated *Harry Potter* characters with the same *last* name: "Evans" comes to mind.

**Q: Are there any instances of J.K. Rowling using the same *first name* for two or more separate characters?**

For example, is there a Zacharias Smith and Zacharias Zabini?

I’m not looking for, say, “Albus Severus Potter” or the like. The names in the epilogue are obvious.

Comment: **Dean** Thomas and the Forest of **Dean**? :-p

Comment: I always thought it was a British thing. Like nicknames - Moaning Myrtle.

Comment: Oh nobody important, just the Dark Lord himself and some random barman called Tom.

Comment: Do Trevor (the toad) and Trevor Birch count?

Comment: Do Hedwig (the owl) & St. Hedwig count?

Comment: Does Lorcan Scammander, Lorcan McLaird,  and Lorcan d'Eath count? How about Hengist of Woodcroft and Hengist of Upper Barnton?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

**Yes**

- **Agatha** Chubb was a wizarding archeologist. Not to be confused with **Agatha** Timms, noted eel farm owner and non-professional gambler.
- **Albert** Runcorne was a Ministry of Magic employee. Not to be confused with **Albert** Boot, The former Minster of Magic (1747-1752).
- **Arthur** A. Levine was a noted publisher of books (including '*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*' and '*Quidditch Through the Ages*'). Not to be confused with **Arthur** Weasley, the father of Harry's best friend, Ron.
- **Augustus** Pye was a Trainee healer at St. Mungo’s. Not to be confused with **Augustus** Rookwood, MoM official and secret Death eater, or **Augustus** Worme, the editor of "*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*".
- **Basil** was the keeper of the portkeys at the Quidditch World Cup. Not to be confused with **Basil** Horton, the founder of the Comet trading company or **Basil** Flack, the former Minister of Magic (1752-1752).
- **Bertie** Higgs was a friend of Tiberius and Rufus Scrimgeour. Not to be confused with **Bertie** Bott, the noted confectioner.
- **Bob** Ogden was the MoM employee who visited Morfin Gaunt. Not to be confused with **Bob** Ollerton, co-founder of the Cleansweep broom company or **Bob**, the MoM employee that Mr. Weasley and Harry met in the elevator en route to Harry’s hearing.
- **Cassandra** Trelawney was a noted seer and grandmother of Sibyll Trelawney. Not to be confused with **Cassandra** Vablatsky, the author of "*Unfogging the Future*".
- **Cornelius** Agrippa was a noted alchemist with his own Frog card. Not to be confused with **Cornelius** Fudge, the former Minister of Magic (1990-1996).
- **Daisy** Pennifold was the inventor of the modern quaffle. Not to be confused with **Daisy** Dodderidge, the first landlord of the Leaky Cauldron.
- **Damocles** was the inventor the Wolfsbane potion. Not to be confused with **Damocles** Rowle, the former Minister of Magic (1718-1726).
- **Dennis** Creevy was a contemporary of Harry Potter at Hogwarts. Not to be confused with **Dennis**, the young boy who co-discovered Tom Riddle's seaside cave or **Dennis**, a member of Dudley's gang.
- **Dugald** McLivert was the head of a prominent wizarding family. Not to be confused with **Dugald** McPhail, the former Minister of Magic (1858-1865).
- **Emeric** the Evil was a known holder of the Elder wand. Not to be confused with Professor **Emeric** Switch, the author of "*A Beginner's Guide to Transfiguration*".
- **Ernest** "*Ernie*" MacMillan was a contemporary of Harry Potter at Hogwarts. Not to be confused with **Ernest** "*Ernie / Ern*" Prang, the driver of the Knight Bus.
- **Frank** Bryce was the Riddle family's gardener.
  Not to be confused with **Frank** Longbottom, Neville's father.
- **Gladys** Gudgeon was a huge fan of Gilderoy Lockhart and would often write to him in hospital after his (ahem) accident. Not to be confused with **Gladys** Boothby, the inventor of the Moontrimmer Broomstick.
- **Harold** Dingle was a contemporary of Harry Potter at Hogwarts. Not to be confused with **Harold** Minchum, the former Minister of Magic (1975-1980).
- **Jacob** Erland was a contemporary of Harry Potter at Hogwarts. Not to be confused with **Jacob** Kowalski, a no-maj baker who assists Newt Scamander.
- **James** "*Jimmy*" Peakes was a contemporary of Harry Potter at Hogwarts. Not to be confused with **James** Potter, Harry's father.
- **Karl** Jenkins is a contemporary of Harry Potter's son Albus at Hogwarts. Not to be confused with **Karl** Broadmoor, a beater for the Falmouth Falcons noted for his violent disconduct and repeated suspensions.
- **Kevin** Whitby was a contemporary of Harry Potter at Hogwarts. Not to be confused with **Kevin**, the little boy at the Quidditch World Cup who attempted to enlarge a slug or **Kevin** Broadmoor, the beater of the Falmouth Falcons from 1958 to 1969.
- **Leonard** Jewkes was the inventor of the Silver Arrow Racing Broom. Not to be confused with **Leonard** Spencer-Moon, the former Minister of Magic (1939-1948).
- **Lily** Moon was a contemporary of Harry Potter at Hogwarts. Not to be confused with **Lily** Potter, Harry Potter's mother.
- **Marcus** Flint was a contemporary of Harry Potter at Hogwarts. Not to be confused with **Marcus** Belby, whose uncle Damocles invented the Wolfsbane potion.
- **Mafalda** was a distant relation of Molly Weasley, not to be confused with **Mafalda** Hopkirk, an employee of the Ministry of Magic.
- **Mary** Cattermole was the Muggle-born wife of Reginald Cattermole. Not to be confused with **Mary** Riddle, the Muggle wife of Thomas Riddle or **Mary** MacDonald, a contemporary of James and Lily Potter, Harry's parents.
- **Millicent** Bulstrode was a contemporary of Harry Potter at Hogwarts. Not to be confused with **Millicent** Bagnold, the former Minister of Magic (1980-1990).
- **Modesty** Rabnott was inspiration for the inventor of the golden snitch. Not to be confused with **Modesty**, a young lady in the employ of Newt Scamander
- **Montague** was a contemporary of Harry Potter at Hogwarts and Slytherin Quidditch player. Not to be confused with **Montague** Knightley, the noted Wizard Chess Champion.
- **Percival** Dumbledore was Albus Dumbledore's father. Not to be confused with **Percival** "*Percy*" Weasley, the brother of Harry's best friend, Ron.
- **Tiberius** Ogden was an Elder of the Wizengamot. Not to be confused with Cormac McLaggen's Uncle **Tiberius**, a member of the Slug Club.
- **Tom** "*the Barman*" was the barman at the Leaky Cauldron. Not to be confused with **Tom** Riddle Jr., a dark wizard of some repute.
- **Wilfred** Elphick was the first man to be gored by an erumpent. Not to be confused with **Wilfred** the Wistful, whose statue can be seen in the hallways of Hogwarts.
- **Wilhelmina** Grubbly-Plank worked as a substitute Care of Magical Creatures teacher. Not to be confused with **Wilhelmina** Tuft, the former Minister of Magic.
- **William** "*Bill*" Weasley was the brother of Harry's best friend, Ron. Not to be confused with **William** "*Bill*" Ollerton, the founder of the Cleansweep broom company or **William/Billy**, the orphan whose pet rabbit a young Tom Riddle killed or **William** "*Honest Willy*” Wagstaff, purveyor of faulty wands and defective defensive charms or **William** "*Willy*" Widdershins, toilet vandal and part-time MoM spy or **William** "*Will*", the toad thief with whom Mundungus does business.

**and last, but not least (and especially relevant given the question)**

- **Zacharias** Smith was a contemporary of Harry Potter at Hogwarts.  Not to be confused with **Zacharias** Mumps, who wrote an account of quidditch in the 14th Century.

Comment: This looks like a nice answer, but what is your source for each name? Where did you find the information for each?

Comment: @Slytherincess - I'm working through http://magical-menagerie.com/wizardry/full-character-listing/ - Only using characters who appear (by name) in one of the 10 books.

Comment: I've ignored all of the "next generation"; Rose Weasley = Rose Zeller, Albus Potter = Albus Dumbledore, etc.

Comment: She really named a bus driver "Prang"? That's a tiny bit tasteless :-P

Comment: @hobbs Oh! That pun never even occurred to me. Such a fitting one, too, given his driving skills.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, and a Shunpike is a side road used to avoid the traffic of a main road (OK I admit I googled that one)

Comment: @MacCooper Funny, that one has been clear to me for years. I guess I just never paid much attention to Ern’s last name—he's always just “Ern(ie)”, whereas Stan is usually Stan Shunpike. I've always read _Shunpike_ as a double pun, implying that he's a bit of a coward as well (he shuns [weapon] pikes).

Comment: Magisterial answer.

Comment: Do you have a reference that Tom Riddle was named Thomas?  I thought her mother asked to named her Tom, and the orphanage probably wouldn't contradict.

Comment: There's a student named Mary too: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Muggles%27_Guide_to_Harry_Potter/Characters/Mary_Macdonald

Comment: @b_jonas - No reference that I can find. Corrected.

Comment: Isn't Montague the surname of the slytherin quidditch player?

Comment: @t.verron - according to the [HP Wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Graham_Montague) his forename does not come from the books (where he's simply known as Montague), it comes from a video game. If it was canon, i'd have matched him with his fellow Slytherin, Graham Pritchard.

Comment: A couple of nitpicks: I can't find "Theodore" Lupin anywhere in canon. Only "Teddy" Lupin. Montague is Harry's contemporary's last name, as opposed to Montague Knightley. I know people think I'm a wet blanket when I'm specific about the sources I want to see, but I trust the books more than any wiki. Also, I'm editing my original post to include the Harry Potter Lexicon, which I do find trustworthy.

Comment: @Slytherincess - There's no evidence (other than from the Harry Potter PS3 Quidditch game) that Montague is his surname. As written, it's used as a first name

Comment: Is there any evidence that Karl Jenkins was named by J.K. Rowling?

Comment: @ibid - Nothing definitive, but *her name* is written in twenty foot high letters outside the theatre, so she's clearly involved in some way.

Comment: @ibid - Per Pottermore "*It’s official. The Cursed Child is the eighth story in the Harry Potter series*"

Comment: @ibid - I was reading an interview with JKR a few days back. She was actually pretty hands on in the filmmaking process, vetoing certain characters, inspecting props, refusing to allow spells to be changed, etc.

Comment: @ibid - I was referring to the earlier HP films.

Comment: @Valorum - Funny, I never [noticed it there](http://i.imgur.com/P4HOgJF.jpg?1) before.

Comment: @ibid - https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-B5sQMHEVgq8/V6D9Bbq4osI/AAAAAAACX8I/ytXB0a1br1UcpEoUuxm79S37auXD5nInACLcB/s800/Harry%2BPotter%2Bcursed%2Bchild%2Bbook%2Bbillboard.jpg

Comment: @Valorum - That's A)Another example of "eight *story*", not "eight *book*", and B)From the marketing team, not from Rowling (who has even corrected people on twitter for calling it "another Harry Potter book").

Comment: @Slytherincess "Teddy" Lupin (and his grandfather "Ted"  Tonks are both Edward, not Theodore. http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Edward_Tonks http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Edward_Lupin Ted=Theodore is pretty much an Americanism. See Theo Nott http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Theodore_Nott

Comment: I think I read somewhere that Cassandra Vlabatsky is actually a pen-name for Cassandra Trelawney, but I can't remember where.

Comment: @ArnaudD. - I don't believe that to be the case.

Comment: The Berties would also be Alberts.

Comment: @Orangedog - Unless it was short for Robert or Bertram, you mean?

Comment: @Valorum then they might match the Bobs instead :)

Comment: I wonder if there’s any other Bellatrix...

Comment: @Bellatrix - As far as I can tell, there's only the one Bellatrix. She's a true original.

Comment: @Valorum Thanks so much for checking for me! :D

Comment: I can't comments on each, but as far as I know, Lily Moon was a previous name for other character (probably Luna Lovegood) that was changed afterwards, so there was no character with such name actually.

Comment: Nicholas Flamel, creator of the Philosophers' Stone, and Nicholas de Mimsey-Porpington, the nearly headless ghost of Hogwarts.

Comment: @Pete - Considered and rejected, I'm afraid. *"with his partner, Nicolas Flamel"* vs, *"I don’t think I’ve introduced myself? Sir Nicholas de Mimsy-Porpington"* - Not spelled the same

Answer (score 32):

I can’t hope to beat @Richard’s frankly excellent answer. But I can highlight one pair* that I’m shocked he missed…

- In *Pottermore* for Playstation Home, there’s a plaque in Gryffindor Tower listing one **Richard Carter** as Gryffindor Quidditch Captain:

  [image]
- At *The Wizarding World of Harry Potter*, there’s a signup sheet for Quidditch which includes **Richard Sky**.

  [image]

---

*I’m scraping the barrel of canonicity here, and you could argue that these names probably weren’t chosen by JK Rowling herself, but once I spotted this I thought it couldn’t go unmentioned.

Comment: You've got my +1 at least :-)

Comment: This joke doesn't work now

Answer (score 3):

Millicent Bulstrode was a Slytherin during Harry's time at Hogwarts. Millicent Bagnold was the minister of magic preceding Fudge.

Comment: indeed! https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ministers-for-magic

Comment: And while this is indeed true, it's also been in my answer (above) for [almost a year and a half](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/96052/29).